# javascript extract date via regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't know much about regular expressions, but I got a string (url) and I'd like to extract the date from it:

```
var myurl = "https://example.com/display/~test/2010/07/06/Day+2.+Test+Page";
```

I'd like to extract `2010/07/06` from it, additionally I would like to have it formatted as `6th of July, 2010`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how the URL can change, you can use something like:

```
\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/
```

The above will extract `/2010/07/06/` (the two slashes just to be safer - you can remove the heading and trailing `\/` to get just `2010/07/06`, but you might have issues if URL contains other parts that may match).

See the online regexp example here:

- http://rubular.com/r/bce4IHyCjW

Here's the jsfiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/zwkDQ/

To format it, take a look e.g. here:

- http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Something along these lines (note you need the function from above):

```
var dt = new Date(2010, 6, 6);
dateFormat(dt, "dS of mmmm, yyyy");
// 6th of June, 2010
```

Comment: Hi icyrock.com, thank you for your swift response! Can you be so nice to provide an example on how to implement this regexp? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks icyrock.com, but the date conversion doesn't work since it only accepts dates without 0's prefixing the day or month. e.g 2010, 7, 6 gets accepted, but 2010, 07, 06 does not.

Comment: @FLX Take a look at the full working example in the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zwkDQ/1/. I am using Firefox, so if it does not work for you and you are using IE, try parsing the strings before (i.e. instead of `p[1]` write `parseInt(p[1])` and so on).

Answer (score 3):

Regex not required. A combination of `split()` and `slice()` will do as well:

```
var myurl = "https://example.com/display/~test/2010/07/06/Day+2.+Test+Page";
var parts = myurl.split("/");  // ["https:", "", "example.com", "display", "~test", "2010", "07", "06", "Day+2.+Test+Page"]
var ymd   = myurl.slice(5,8);  // ["2010", "07", "06"]
var date  = new Date(ymd);     // Tue Jul 06 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
```

There are several comprehensive date formatting libraries, I suggest you take one of those and do not try to roll your own.

Comment: Passing an array to the `Date()` constructor won't work across all browsers.  In Internet Explorer, you'd have to use `new Date(ymd[0], ymd[1] - 1, ymd[2]);`.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks for the hint. As you might have guessed, I did not try it in IE.

Comment: yeah, I did guess that :-) I always remember that Internet Explorer 8 and lower's Date parsing is very poor.  I think it's improved in 9, thanks to ECMAScript 5.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, but the date conversion doesn't work since it only accepts dates without 0's prefixing the day or month. e.g 2010, 7, 6 gets accepted, but 2010, 07, 06 does not.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myurl = "https://example.com/display/~test/2010/07/06/Day+2.+Test+Page";

var re = /(\d{4})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})/
var months = ["","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

var parts = myurl.match(re)

var year = parseInt(parts[1]);
var month = parseInt(parts[2],10);
var day = parseInt(parts[3],10);

alert( months[month] + " " + day + ", " + year );
```