# Retrieving Date from a URL string in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, regex, url, date

I have a WordPress site, and am using AJAX to update the archive rather than page reloads (in very basic terms).

So I can either be passing:

```
http://mysite.com/events/2012/10/17
http://mysite.com/events/2012/10
http://mysite.com/events/2012
```

I am looking for a JS/jQuery regex method that will retrieve any of these. So far I have the following:

```
var linkUrl = 'http://mysite.com/events/2012/10';
var linkDate = linkUrl.match(/\d{4}(\/\d{2})+/);
console.log( linkDate ); // output - ["2012/10", "/10", index: 8, input: "/events/2012/10"]
```

It appears that it's finding 2 matches, the second of which is not what I want. I'm sure it's a simple thing in my regex.

Comment: This is clearly example code. In your actual code, is the url in an `<a>` element that's being clicked?

Comment: Did you check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478426/javascript-extract-date-via-regular-expression ?

Comment: @CrazyTrain yes this is example code, the linkUrl is being populated by $(this).attr('href') which is essentially giving me what I have displayed above.

Comment: @JonathanNaguin I didn't, and it is definitely helpful, however this expression is a little more advanced than `/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/` as that ALWAYS looks for day only, not monthly. I discovered the solution - posted below.

Comment: Why do you care how many matches it returns? Just use `linkDate[0]`.

Comment: @EricHolmes: In that case, I'd suggest using `this.pathname` in order to reduce the string that you're searching down to the path. Also, it's *much* faster than `$(this).attr("href");`

Comment: @CrazyTrain I am - and good call. I just put in the whole url for the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have discovered the solution within my lovely O'Reilly Regular Expression book.

after looking at my regex again, I realized that the month[and day] expression is surrounded by brackets, which apparently means to capture the subpattern. The solution was this.

```
var linkUrl = "/events/2012/10/25";
var linkDate = linkUrl.match(/\d{4}(?:\/\d{2})*/);
// output - ["2012/10/25", index: 8, input: "/events/2012/10/25"]
```

I added `?:` within the brackets, which tells `match` to not capture the substring. Now I receive `2012/10/17` or `2012/10` respectvely, depending on the URL.

Also notice the single value being returned, due to properly excluding subpatterns.

Answer (score 2):

I would try this regexp `/(\d{4})(?:\/(\d{2}))?(?:\/(\d{2}))?$/`:

```
'http://mysite.com/events/2012'.match(/(\d{4})(?:\/(\d{2}))?(?:\/(\d{2}))?$/)
// => ["2012", "2012", undefined, undefined]

'http://mysite.com/events/2012/03'.match(/(\d{4})(?:\/(\d{2}))?(?:\/(\d{2}))?$/)
// => ["2012/03", "2012", "03", undefined]

'http://mysite.com/events/2012/03/21'.match(/(\d{4})(?:\/(\d{2}))?(?:\/(\d{2}))?$/)
// => ["2012/03/21", "2012", "03", "21"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @dfsq. Yours would work, but it looks kind of messy to me (too many brackets). see my answer for the most efficient method.

Comment: @EricHolmes: your "too many brackets" sounds just like the "too many notes" anecdote. Believe it or not, every one of them is necessary.

Comment: @thg435 Actually, they arent. See how his results have `03` and `21`, and `undefined` ? That is because the nested brackets (while not necessary) are creating a sub-pattern capture that is not being ignored. Mine is cleaner, more efficient, and properly blocking out subpatterns.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but I can't see how your regexp can possibly help: `'http://mysite.com/events/2012'.match(/\d{4}(?:\/\d{2})+/)` => `null`. `'http://mysite.com/events/2012/02'.match(/\d{4}(?:\/\d{2})+/)` => `["2012/02"]`. To me it does not look very helpful. But as long as it works for you, great!

Comment: Good point - my situation always deals with at LEAST monthly archives. It should be this - `/\d{4}(?:\/\d{2})*/`. (updating answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
(?<=/)[0-9]{4}(/[0-9]{1,2})?(/[0-9]{1,2})?
```